# UIImage as patterns

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, design-patterns

I am trying to get UIImage as a pattern. So, I have one image and I want to fill UIImageView with this image without stretching the pattern. 
I know you can get UIColor with pattern but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Have You tried `UIColor *patternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern"]];
`

Comment: @BuntyMadan OP specifically mentioned in question that he does not want UIColor with pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Amar. I found function to convert UIColor to UIImage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `UIImage`'s methods for pattern.

1)`(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets`

2)`(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode`

Its better to have 1 pixel width Image.

Answer (score 0):

If your UIImageView size is static you could create a new pattern image from the image you have and then use that image in UIImageView.

Comment: No it is not static. I am trying to fill slider.